# can ping but cannot browse

Tags: ping

OS = Ubuntu 15.04
Browser = chrome

Problem: Unable to browse websites - i can only ping them 
Checked host files they are pointing to nameserver 192.168.10.20 (company DNS) - I had changed this earlier

Should they be pointing to Local host or home router?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing your DNS to 8.8.8.8? It's Google's DNS servers and works most of the time. Comment if it works.

Comment: OP might not know how to do that, improve your answer by providing an example

Answer (score 0):

> Problem: Unable to browse websites - i can only ping them Checked host files they are pointing to nameserver 192.168.10.20 (company DNS) - I had changed this earlier.

Apparently your DNS configuration works as you can ping the domain names of websites. You may prove it more by using `nslookup website_domain` to see if it correctly returns the IP address of the domain. Hence I suppose it's due to your system proxy settings. Go to **System Preferences -> Network -> Network Proxy**, set it to **None** or **Automatic** then **Apply system wide**.